# Can't access boot menu or bios to do a clean install

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 18 on a computer (Dell Optiplex 990, yeah I know, it was $25) via a USB stick. I had just gotten the computer, so it was totally blank, and I was able to push f12 to enter the boot menu, no problem.

I messed something up while trying to set it up, so rather than trying to fix it I figured it'd be easier to do a clean install. Except now I can't seem to access the boot menu again to do so. Instead, no matter what I do it goes to Grub2, where I don't have an option to boot from USB.

There's no problem with the USB itself (I tried it on another computer and it works), and obviously I was able to use that USB port before to get Ubuntu the first time. I tried F2 for the BIOS menu, which is what the manual I found on Google tells me I should be pressing, but that also goes to Grub2.

I've gone through all the related threads I can find, so sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find any that seem to be helpful / that are written in a way I understand, I'm pretty out of my depth at this point.

Comment: Try to attach external keyboard and press F2 exectly when Dell logo appears.

Comment: I am using an external keyboard, and have tried several dozen times pressing at different times. The computer manual also says that pressing too early can block it and not to press until the keyboard lights up, but it doesn't light up until half a second before Grub comes up, so that could be something?

Comment: a little severe solution, but you can unplug your HDD. Your system then should boot to BIOS, as long as there will be no ROM with grub.

Comment: Yikes. Anything that doesn’t involve taking apart my computer? I can try, of course, but...

Comment: Also, if I do that, at what point do I plug the HDD  back in? Just after it boots to BIOS?

Comment: You can always access BIOS/UEFI. That you're unable to do it tells us you aren't doing it right. Just power on and immediately and intermittently press the key mentioned in your user's manual for that purpose. F2, not F12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, counterintuitively, I had to wait until well, well after it had the Dell logo and ‘Press F12 For Boot Menu’ written on the screen, like 2-3 seconds after. From what the manual said, you need to wait for the keyboard to initialize (it will light up), and pressing F12 before that will make it ignore any subsequent keypresses, even if you’re tapping repeatedly.

In my case, the keyboard actually didn’t initialize until the Dell logo had disappeared and the screen was blank.

Answer (score 0):

To enter Bios keep hitting the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key while booting up. I have a dell optiplex 520.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the RESET switch for 3 seconds and you should get to the BIOS. Works on every computer I own (or have owned).

**EDIT:** Just saw that you've fixed it yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the advice anyway, good to know for future reference!